# как создать двумерный динамический массив с типом char

Tags: c++, c, массивы

мне нужно сделать двумерный массив типа char размер которого можно поменять после компиляции `char A[n][n]` `n` вводит пользователь  я знаю нужно делать через ``` malloc``calloc ``` и указателями но я запутался

помогите разобратся!!

вот код

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0, m = 0;
    print_welcome();
    print_enter_board_size();
    n = multipler_n();
    char** board = malloc (n*sizeof(char*));
        for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
    board[i] = malloc(m*sizeof(char));
    }
    print_board(**board, n); //ругается на это EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    system("Pause");
}
}
```

Comment: Показывайте Ваш код, посмотрим, покритикуем

Comment: добавил код скажите в чем я ошибся

Comment: цикл по `m` . А размер для памяти выделили `n`. Переменная `m == 0` . !!